# How to remove driver that is set to the constraint via Python?

Tags: python, drivers

I want to remove a driver that is driving to "Enabled" in the constraint of posebone through Python command.

If it is a driver for the transform of the posebone, I know how to do it.

```
bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones[name].driver_remove('location')
```

So how do I access or remove driver set to the properties of the constraint?

I searched by the following script, but could not find it.

```
print(bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.animation_data.drivers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just right click a property and select "Copy as Driver" it will give you the value in question.

[image]

Seems like this does the trick:

```
const = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].constraints["Clamp To"]
const.driver_remove('influence')
```

Comment: Fantastic! I got it.
Thank you!